# Android WebView tag a can not start a intent with tel Uri

Tags: android, html, android-webview

**Click Common tag a contains 'tel:' Uri in HTML can not start a intent in Android.

Here is my Android code:**

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); //no cache
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    //This method will only be invoked with GET request
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //Log.d("DEBUG-URL","url:"+url);
            if(url.startsWith(WebView.SCHEME_TEL)){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                        Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**When I click the url in WebView, net: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME throws.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I add click event,  invoke event.preventDefault(), and then I use Ajax GET request. This problem was resolved.**

```
$("#a_get").on("click",function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();//invalidate
                            $.ajax({
                                   type: "GET",
                                   url: a_href,
                                   success: function(result){

                                   },
                                   error: function(result){

                                   }
                            });
                        });
```